# Вернуть кнопке "...", если весь текст в text не влезает

Tags: android-sdk

Всем привет. Определил новый background для кнопки. Если в android:text максимальное количество символов превышает допустимое, то три точки не появляются, как при стандартном бэкграунде. Подскажите, как их вернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.

`android:singleLine="true"`, хоть, почему то и студия говорит, что его плохо использовать.

Comment: Студия права - это устаревший способ. Сейчас надо заменять его на `android:maxLines="1"`. P.S. если вы не будете добавлять другие метки к вопросам и продолжат не замечать. Добавляйте хотя бы `android`. На метку `android-sdk` почти никто не подписан и ваш вопрос никто не видит